# Mixing bootstrap with a non-responsive div contents?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My boss has asked me to update a portion of our website using bootstrap, but only the header. I am using a static navbar for our header, and the rest of the page is a mess of table soup (I think the site was written 10 years ago). The way the code is structured right now is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    < code for the navbar ></code for the navbar>
    <Table>
         <content of website>
    </Table>
</div>
```

It looks great on desktop but on mobile it falls apart and zooms into the top left corner of the website. You cannot see all of the header or about 65% of the webpage. I am using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Rewriting the page in bootstrap is not an option, as we will re-use this header across at least 165 different html files. So I guess what I am asking is it possible to take a non-responsive part of a webpage, slap it into a responsive element so it zooms-out the contents based on screen size?

Cheers!

Comment: you can wrap your elements in `col-xs-n` classes defined in bootstrap's grid..

Answer (score 0):

Your route of least resistance will be to wrap the table in `<div class="table-responsive"></div>`, like:

```
<div class="container">
    < code for the navbar ></code for the navbar>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
            <content of website>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will make the table scroll on mobile. [See the docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

Comment: I did try that, but it gave us a look that we were not happy with. The html is written in a way so that all of the formatting is basically done via tables, so very rarely is a table actually a table @.@. I think I may try to convince my boss to redo the whole thing in Bootstrap.

Comment: That would be the wisest solution. I feel your pain though--I went through the same thing and ended up re-writing it all for bootstrap. The results are well worth the effort.

Comment: @smusings, I have to agree. The formatting styles are really not compatible and trying to force them will be like oil and water. You might be able to do it, but it'll be more painful than it's worth, even with 165 different files.

Comment: The other option is to create a custom header without bootstrap to fit the needs of the project.

Comment: Ew...yeah sounds like the site is long overdue for a rewrite

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood I suggested that, but the idea was shot down. We want to transition to a mobile friendly website due to Google's "mobile-geddon", so I think this was going to happen one way or another.

Comment: Oh ya, if you're trying to go mobile tables will simply not work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are your `body` and `html` both `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` ? Just to make sure.